# How to get a Json object and store it in a Hashmap

Tags: java, servlets

In my dopost, I'm trying to get a Json object from the request and then create a Profile object from that request using fromJson and then store it in my hashmap. When I try and do that in my code and print out my hashmap, that new profile i just created just prints out {id=0} but all other profiles that I hard coded in print out fine. My new profile doesn't print out my username lastname age etc.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

What I'm trying to sent as json

```
{
"4": {
    "id": "9",
    "username": "gfgf",
    "lastname": "hgfh",
    "favTeam": "Manc city",
    "age": "51"
}
}
```

my code

```
public class ProfileServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
protected HashMap<Integer, Profile> team = new HashMap<Integer, Profile>();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Gson gson = new Gson();

public ProfileServlet() 
{

    Profile profile1 = new Profile(1,"bob","bee","Manc city","21");
    Profile profile2 = new Profile(2,"billy","smith","Dortmud","25");
    Profile profile3 = new Profile(3,"john","jamesd","Aston Villa","44");

    int id = 1;
    int id2 = 2;
    int id3 = 3;

    team.put(id,profile1);
    team.put(id2,profile2); 
    team.put(id3,profile3);
}

public void sendAsJson(HttpServletResponse response, Object obj) throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    String jsonString = gson.toJson(obj);


    out.print(jsonString);
    out.flush();

}

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
 {
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 
    int counter = 0;
    boolean breakloop = false;
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String path = request.getPathInfo();



    if(path == null || path.equals("/"))
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        String myprofile = buffer.toString();
        Profile newp = gson.fromJson(myprofile, Profile.class);

        //loop to create my IDs in order
        while(breakloop == false)
        {
            if(!team.containsKey(counter))
            {
                newp.id = counter;
                breakloop = true;
            }
            else
                counter++;          

        }       

        team.put(newp.id,newp);
        sendAsJson(response,team);

    }
    else
    {
        response.sendError(400, "Incorrect request, make sure you typed the body correctly!");
    }



}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, nothing is wrong with my code but the problem was in my json request. This worked for me.

How my Json works, I guess adding those outer brackets somehow didn't get my full request

```
{
  "id": "9",
  "username": "gfgf",
  "lastname": "hgfh",
  "favTeam": "Manc city",
  "age": "51"
}
```